# How to get julian Date from Date Control using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a web page where user are asked to enter date, now i want to get Julian Date which can be be achieved by using on click event.

I need 3 digit Julian Date in small text box s for 18/05/2016 JD will be 139:

[image: 1]

Edit : Sorry I was new to SO, and now thought that I have to rephrase my question. I was asking to get JD after selecting date picker in jQuery. I know the logic of JD calculation. So I upon checking it thorough, i found out **OnChange function**  associated in DatePicker and we can set an any value on this event.
 I find out the answer.

Comment: add you html code and script ? what you tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post code and effort

Comment: I know how to calculate JD and got that formula, question I was asking in on DatePicker..